# Unknown command: 'collectstatic' while deploying a Mezzanine app on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, mezzanine

I am trying to deploy a Mezzanine app I have built, but I am running into many issues with the settings.py file. I have tried what has been suggested in quite a few tutorials for getting Mezzanine apps on Heroku, and none of them have worked, plus I am now confused as to what changes I have made. When I run things locally there are no issues.

Currently I have my urls set as in this post: https://gist.github.com/joshfinnie/4046138

and this is my settings.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static'),
)

######################
# MEZZANINE SETTINGS #
######################

# The following settings are already defined with default values in
# the ``defaults.py`` module within each of Mezzanine's apps, but are
# common enough to be put here, commented out, for convenient
# overriding. Please consult the settings documentation for a full list
# of settings Mezzanine implements:
# http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/configuration.html#default-settings

# Controls the ordering and grouping of the admin menu.
#
# ADMIN_MENU_ORDER = (
#     ("Content", ("pages.Page", "blog.BlogPost",
#        "generic.ThreadedComment", ("Media Library", "fb_browse"),)),
#     ("Site", ("sites.Site", "redirects.Redirect", "conf.Setting")),
#     ("Users", ("auth.User", "auth.Group",)),
# )

# A three item sequence, each containing a sequence of template tags
# used to render the admin dashboard.
#
# DASHBOARD_TAGS = (
#     ("blog_tags.quick_blog", "mezzanine_tags.app_list"),
#     ("comment_tags.recent_comments",),
#     ("mezzanine_tags.recent_actions",),
# )

# A sequence of templates used by the ``page_menu`` template tag. Each
# item in the sequence is a three item sequence, containing a unique ID
# for the template, a label for the template, and the template path.
# These templates are then available for selection when editing which
# menus a page should appear in. Note that if a menu template is used
# that doesn't appear in this setting, all pages will appear in it.

# PAGE_MENU_TEMPLATES = (
#     (1, "Top navigation bar", "pages/menus/dropdown.html"),
#     (2, "Left-hand tree", "pages/menus/tree.html"),
#     (3, "Footer", "pages/menus/footer.html"),
# )

# A sequence of fields that will be injected into Mezzanine's (or any
# library's) models. Each item in the sequence is a four item sequence.
# The first two items are the dotted path to the model and its field
# name to be added, and the dotted path to the field class to use for
# the field. The third and fourth items are a sequence of positional
# args and a dictionary of keyword args, to use when creating the
# field instance. When specifying the field class, the path
# ``django.models.db.`` can be omitted for regular Django model fields.
#
# EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS = (
#     (
#         # Dotted path to field.
#         "mezzanine.blog.models.BlogPost.image",
#         # Dotted path to field class.
#         "somelib.fields.ImageField",
#         # Positional args for field class.
#         ("Image",),
#         # Keyword args for field class.
#         {"blank": True, "upload_to": "blog"},
#     ),
#     # Example of adding a field to *all* of Mezzanine's content types:
#     (
#         "mezzanine.pages.models.Page.another_field",
#         "IntegerField", # 'django.db.models.' is implied if path is omitted.
#         ("Another name",),
#         {"blank": True, "default": 1},
#     ),
# )

# Setting to turn on featured images for blog posts. Defaults to False.
#
# BLOG_USE_FEATURED_IMAGE = True

# If True, the south application will be automatically added to the
# INSTALLED_APPS setting.
USE_SOUTH = True

#BLOG_SLUG = ""

########################
# MAIN DJANGO SETTINGS #
########################

# People who get code error notifications.
# In the format (('Full Name', 'email@example.com'),
#                ('Full Name', 'anotheremail@example.com'))
ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
    ('Jessie Alvarez', 'jessiea@stanford.edu'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

# If you set this to True, Django will use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en"

# Supported languages
_ = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
)

# A boolean that turns on/off debug mode. When set to ``True``, stack traces
# are displayed for error pages. Should always be set to ``False`` in
# production. Best set to ``True`` in local_settings.py
DEBUG = False

# Whether a user's session cookie expires when the Web browser is closed.
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = False

# Tuple of IP addresses, as strings, that:
#   * See debug comments, when DEBUG is true
#   * Receive x-headers
INTERNAL_IPS = ("127.0.0.1",)

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
    "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ("mezzanine.core.auth_backends.MezzanineBackend",)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# The numeric mode to set newly-uploaded files to. The value should be
# a mode you'd pass directly to os.chmod.
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644


#############
# DATABASES #
#############

import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}


#########
# PATHS #
#########

#import os

# Full filesystem path to the project.
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Name of the directory for the project.
PROJECT_DIRNAME = PROJECT_ROOT.split(os.sep)[-1]

# Every cache key will get prefixed with this value - here we set it to
# the name of the directory the project is in to try and use something
# project specific.
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = PROJECT_DIRNAME

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, STATIC_URL.strip("/"))

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + "media/"

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, *MEDIA_URL.strip("/").split("/"))

# Package/module name to import the root urlpatterns from for the project.
ROOT_URLCONF = "%s.urls" % PROJECT_DIRNAME

# Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates"
# or "C:/www/django/templates".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),)


################
# APPLICATIONS #
################

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.redirects",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "mezzanine.boot",
    "mezzanine.conf",
    "mezzanine.core",
    "mezzanine.generic",
    "mezzanine.blog",
    "mezzanine.forms",
    "mezzanine.pages",
    "mezzanine.galleries",
    "mezzanine.twitter",
    "gunicorn",
    #"mezzanine.accounts",
    #"mezzanine.mobile",
)

# List of processors used by RequestContext to populate the context.
# Each one should be a callable that takes the request object as its
# only parameter and returns a dictionary to add to the context.
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "mezzanine.conf.context_processors.settings",
    "mezzanine.pages.context_processors.page",
)

# List of middleware classes to use. Order is important; in the request phase,
# these middleware classes will be applied in the order given, and in the
# response phase the middleware will be applied in reverse order.
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.UpdateCacheMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.request.CurrentRequestMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForDeviceMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForHostMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.AdminLoginInterfaceSelectorMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.SitePermissionMiddleware",
    # Uncomment the following if using any of the SSL settings:
    # "mezzanine.core.middleware.SSLRedirectMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware",
    "mezzanine.core.middleware.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
)

# Store these package names here as they may change in the future since
# at the moment we are using custom forks of them.
PACKAGE_NAME_FILEBROWSER = "filebrowser_safe"
PACKAGE_NAME_GRAPPELLI = "grappelli_safe"

#########################
# OPTIONAL APPLICATIONS #
#########################

# These will be added to ``INSTALLED_APPS``, only if available.
OPTIONAL_APPS = (
    "debug_toolbar",
    "django_extensions",
    "compressor",
    PACKAGE_NAME_FILEBROWSER,
    PACKAGE_NAME_GRAPPELLI,
)

###################
# DEPLOY SETTINGS #
###################

# These settings are used by the default fabfile.py provided.
# Check fabfile.py for defaults.

# FABRIC = {
#     "SSH_USER": "", # SSH username for host deploying to
#     "HOSTS": ALLOWED_HOSTS[:1], # List of hosts to deploy to (eg, first host)
#     "DOMAINS": ALLOWED_HOSTS, # Domains for public site
#     "REPO_URL": "ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/project", # Project's repo URL
#     "VIRTUALENV_HOME":  "", # Absolute remote path for virtualenvs
#     "PROJECT_NAME": "", # Unique identifier for project
#     "REQUIREMENTS_PATH": "requirements.txt", # Project's pip requirements
#     "GUNICORN_PORT": 8000, # Port gunicorn will listen on
#     "LOCALE": "en_US.UTF-8", # Should end with ".UTF-8"
#     "DB_PASS": "", # Live database password
#     "ADMIN_PASS": "", # Live admin user password
#     "SECRET_KEY": SECRET_KEY,
#     "NEVERCACHE_KEY": NEVERCACHE_KEY,
# }


##################
# LOCAL SETTINGS #
##################

# Allow any settings to be defined in local_settings.py which should be
# ignored in your version control system allowing for settings to be
# defined per machine.
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass


####################
# DYNAMIC SETTINGS #
####################

# set_dynamic_settings() will rewrite globals based on what has been
# defined so far, in order to provide some better defaults where
# applicable. We also allow this settings module to be imported
# without Mezzanine installed, as the case may be when using the
# fabfile, where setting the dynamic settings below isn't strictly
# required.
try:
    from mezzanine.utils.conf import set_dynamic_settings
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    set_dynamic_settings(globals())
```

Comment: @rajasimon: while deploying it says 'Collectstatic configuration error. To debug, run 'heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'. When I run that I get 'Unknown command: collectstatic'

Comment: i have doubt. why you give  collectstatic command.. just run the runserver then heroku will do collectstatic ..

Comment: you can see heroku will run collectstatic or not

Comment: @rajasimon heroku uses collectstatic. That's why it complains about it being configured incorrectly when I deploy.

Comment: heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --dry-run --noinput

Comment: @rajasimon I get the exact same error.

Comment: have you got dj-static ..?

Answer (score 4):

Run `heroku run python manage.py help` – at least for me that helped to get a more accurate description of the error. For me, the problem wasn't that collectstatic was missing, but that an environment variable wasn't set. That cause created the sympton of collectstatic to appear missing.

Comment: 'heroku run python manage.py help check' was the full command that showed me a missing environment variable. (Added subcommand, 'check'). I had same symptoms of collectstatic missing. Setting the unrelated environment variable fixed everything.

Comment: So... which variable?

Comment: That'll depend on your specific app.